# Angular 2.0 : Does Typescript support all the features of ES6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular

Typescript started by claiming that it is a superset of Javascript. Now with ES6 around the corner. Does the current typescript transpiler/compiler support all the es6 features and syntax as it is or does it deviate from es6 interms of syntax for module export/import, arrow functions, etc?

I am asking because I am trying to learn angular 2.0 but am not able to decide whether to follow typescript path or vanilla JS path.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like the reverse of [Which ES6 features are implemented in Typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22260978/1048572)

Comment: It [doesn't seem to support `let` in loop bodies](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html#let-in-closures), for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding features, see [What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript)  and the [Roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap).  (<strike>There doesn't seem to be any page that directly compares ES6/ES2015 features to TypeScript though.</strike> See @alexpod's answer.)

I suggest you use TypeScript, if for nothing else, for the extra type checking.  When Angular converted their code over to TypeScript, it revealed a number of bugs.

TypeScript's primary purpose is not to add features to JavaScript – as is the purpose of ES2015 – but to make it easier and safer for developers to write and maintain large JavaScript applications. The primary benefit of TypeScript shows up before your application runs – when you're writing or maintaining code. Intellisense, code completion, type checking, etc.

Comment: You mentioned "Intellisense, code completion, type checking, etc." How do I use these features. Do they come with typescript itself or do I need to use Visual Studio for that?

Comment: @jackOfAll, you need to use a TypeScript-aware editor, see [this list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support).

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#typescript). It will show you what typescript and other transpilers/environments support right now.

Answer (score 2):

On top of [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968837/127826), I should add that TypeScript and other transpilers allow you to use several ES6 features today. I wouldn't dream of launching a public facing website built entirely using ES6 today (early 2017), because old browsers don't die easy. TypeScript removes that inhibition altogether and also adds some innovations of its own.

Comment: This answer is good because it is true of transpilers in general, that they remove the blockades to using new features now, and still support older browsers