# Angular 2. ES5 vs TypeScript

Tags: angular

I'm starting to learn Angular 2 and from the start I have to choose more preferable language. For me it is a choice between JS and TS.

To be honest, I am not a big fan of TypeScript because I think it is some kind of intermediate language from ES5 to ES6 (correct me if i'm wrong).

But with ES5 second version of Angular looks a bit ugly and seems like angular team suggest to use TS. Don't know why ng team not chose ES6 + Babel.

On this post I just want to know pros and cons of using Angular 2 with TypeScript and ES5.

Comment: Essentially the same question (despite the title): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968665/angular-2-0-does-typescript-support-all-the-features-of-es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not a big fan of TypeScript because I think it is some kind of intermediate language from ES5 to ES6 (correct me if i'm wrong).

It is not, if anything, TS is supposed to extend ES6 (not entirely truth yet).

At this point I would consider TS for one simple reason that trust me will save you a lot of headaches and make you more productive: There is very little documentation about Angular 2 and 90% of the docs you'll find are written in TS. simply go to the Developer Guides in the main webpage: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ and compare the 4 JS sections against the 16 TS Sections.

See: [What are the pros and cons using ES5 JavaScript for Angular 2 applications and those for using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808866/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-using-es5-javascript-for-angular-2-applications-and-t/34809206)

Comment: This flexibility feature will divide the world :(